# Problem with the connection between postgresql and flutter

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart

So I'm developing a Flutter project that interact with PostgreSQL Database with Dart and I have a problem with the connection between PostgreSQL and Flutter.

Any ideas why I'm getting this kind of error:
[image: this is the code and the error that i get]

Comment: The most likely reason is that the firewall on 10.0.0.2 is blocking inbound connections or the postgres server is only listening on localhost. As an aside about your Flutter code, you obviously must not perform any database operations in `build` as they all take time to finish and `build` must not wait for anything. When calling `connection.open()` you should `await` the result, which means you need to do that somewhere you can make `async`. This is one of the topics about Flutter that confuses some people initially, but since it is so fundamental there's lots of good articles about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thankfully I found the error. I was pointing at `10.0.0.2`, but I had to put `10.0.2.2`.